# Как правильно переопределить переменную?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Нужно после запроса на сервер вставить содержимое ответа в переменную `data`.

Но по факту сразу после цикла `for` все данные в `data` добавлены, но при рендере (могу ошибаться в терминологии, при `return`) `data` все равно пустая.

```
   // ...
    const data = []
    // ...
    const handleChange = event => {
        const axios = require('axios');
        const value = event.target.value;
        const url = '/search'
        axios.get(url, {
          params: { value: value }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            data.push(response.data[i]);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // ...
        })
        .then(function () {
          // ...
        });
      };
    return (<div>
      // ... data.map () здесь data пустая
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: А этот код внутри функции render() находится? const data к чему относится?

Comment: нет, внутри `const`

Comment: Проблема в том, что запрос асинхронный и data возвращается до того, как пройдет запрос, попробуйте в последнем `then` прописать рендер.

Comment: @evans Я про прямо весь код, который вы приложили - он может быть или внутри функции render, или внутри class {} (тогда непонятно к чему относится return).
Но в любом случае, скорее всего data - локальная переменная, и становится пустой при втором рендере. Скорее всего вам стоит использовать this.state / this.setState({data: response.data}) вместо неё

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно переменную `data` добавить в локальный `state`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

в `axios` обновлять переменную через `setData(prev => [...prev, response.data[i])`

Зачем в цикле это делать? Нельзя весь респонс поместить в переменную?
тогда будет просто `setData(response.data)`